# Excel VBA Match First & Last Names from sheet 1 to sheet 2 and delete all matches on sheet 1

Tags: vba, excel, string-matching, delete-row

Some help with this one would be awesome.

In "sheet 3" I have a database of "Last name" in Column "B" & "First Name" in Column "C".
The same list of names is also in "Sheet 2", "Last name" in Column E & "First Name" in Column "F"

I need to delete all matches from sheet 2 at the click of a button. I also need to be able to change how many rows down "sheet 2" the matches will stop, for example is will only look at the first 600 rows on "sheet 2".

I hope this was explained simply enough.

This is the code i have been using to clear specific ranges however it is horrible and i may need to change the ranges, which makes this method very impractical.

```
Sub ClearSelection()

    Sheets("ADULT Sign On Sheet").Select
    Range("E6:F36").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("E42:F72").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("E78:F108").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("E114:F144").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("E150:F180").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("E186:F216").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("E222:F252").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("E258:F288").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("E294:F324").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("E330:F360").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Edit your question to include the code please.

Comment: SO is not a code outsourcing community.  As @Gareth mentioned, you need to share some of your code and where you are stuck to get help.

Comment: I apologise I wasn't aware. I have no coding experience and have no code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the politics of the site's intentions aside for a minute, see if this can get you started on applying some VBA for yourself.

```
Sub ClearSelection_and_DeDupe()
    Dim r As Long, v As Variant, ws3 As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Sheets("ADULT Sign On Sheet")
        For r = 6 To 330 Step 36
            .Cells(r, 5).Resize(31, 2).ClearContents
        Next r
    End With

    On Error GoTo fìn
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet 3")
    With Sheets("Sheet 2")
        r = Application.Max(.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row, .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).row)
        v = InputBox(prompt:="How many rows to look at?", Default:=r)
        For r = Application.Sum(v) To 2 Step -1
            If CBool(Application.CountIfs(ws3.Columns(2), .Cells(r, 5).Value, ws3.Columns(3), .Cells(r, 6).Value)) Then _
                .Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
        Next r
    End With
fìn:
    Set ws3 = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

That code will perform exactly as you've described and I've tightened up your earlier cell clearing routine by finding the pattern to the areas and looping through them. TBH, that loop code could just as easily be written as:

```
Sheets("ADULT Sign On Sheet").Range("E6:F36,E42:F72,E78:F108,E114:F144,E150:F180,E186:F216,E222:F252,E258:F288,E294:F324,E330:F360").ClearContents
```

... but the 'For ... Next` loop looks cooler.

So see if you can make sense of the snippets I've provided and incorporate them as a command button. There is no end to the amount of instructional material available on how to do that and this site's (among others) previously asked Q&A's are an excellent resource for that.

If you are having trouble incorporating this for your own purposes, make sure that you post back with a description of the problem together with any sample showing your own effort. Good luck!

Comment: This is great, and very helpful for helping me understand how to apply this method.